# compute.requireOsLogin violated in dataproc serverless

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I am trying to create a batch in dataproc to run my job. After creating the batch it is failing with the error **compute.requireOsLogin violated for project ...**

In my organization policy this policy(compute.requireOsLogin) is enforced. Any way to mitigate this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compute.requireOsLogin` needs to be disabled if you want to run Dataproc Serverless. This is as per documentation of Dataproc serverless as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/overview).

If you are interested in supporting Dataproc serverless while `compute.requireOsLogin` is enabled please follow and upvote this [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/226946271)

Do accept the answer if it helped in resolving your question.